# How can i change selected form 2 if i select option form 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">1<option>
  <option value="2">2<option>
  <option value="3">3<option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="one">one<option>
  <option value="two">two<option>
  <option value="three">three<option>
</select>
```

How can I change the selected `<option>` of the `<select id="select2">` to `<option value="one">` if I select any option of `<select id="select1">`?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change & http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: $('#select1').change(function(){     
           $("select#select2").prop('selectedIndex',$("#select1 option:selected").index());    
        });

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will help you

```js
$(()=>{
  
  $('#select1').change(()=>{
       $('#select2').val('one');              
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">

<option value="1">1<option>
<option value="2">2<option>
<option value="3">3<option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
<option value="one">one<option>

<option value="two">two<option>

<option value="three">three<option>

</select>
```